# Add a new SPView to an SPList

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would need to create views and add them to lists programmatically. In the SPList method there is a Views Property of type SPViewCollection. 
This has an add method. But this method does not accept a full XML schema. It is divided into a number of paramaters (where you set the query, joins etc). I would need a method where I can just pass the full XML. 
I was thinking of first creating a 'Dummy' view using this Add method and then reading the View back, and finally using the SetViewXml. 
But it is a bit of dirty approach - perhaps there is something better and simpler that I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I don't believe you need XML.  You should only need to add the columns using a string collection.

```
  using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
  {

     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating the list");

     //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; //use this in an application page no need in a dll

     web.Lists.Add("Customers", "Store informations about my Company Customers", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

     web.Update();



     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating the Fields");

     SPList myNewList = web.Lists["Customers"];

     myNewList.Fields.Add("First Name", SPFieldType.Text, false);

     myNewList.Fields.Add("Last Name", SPFieldType.Text, false);

     myNewList.Fields.Add("Adress", SPFieldType.Text, false);

     myNewList.Fields.Add("City", SPFieldType.Text, false);

     myNewList.Fields.Add("Latest Purchase Date", SPFieldType.DateTime, false);

     myNewList.Fields.Add("Sales Comments", SPFieldType.Note, false);

     myNewList.Update();



     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating the view");

     System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection strColl = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

     strColl.Add("Title");

     strColl.Add("First Name");

     strColl.Add("Last Name");

     strColl.Add("Adress");

     strColl.Add("City");

     strColl.Add("Latest Purchase Date");

     strColl.Add("Sales Comments");

     myNewList.Views.Add("Summary", strColl, @"", 100, true, true, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);

     myNewList.Update();

 }
```